# How to decode parameter with space in URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I try to extract parameter from URL, but one parameter has space which is replaced with "+",
so the parameter I extract is "iphone+4", but actually it is "iphone 4", how can I convert to the second form, decodeURIComponent does not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"iPhone+4".replace("+"," ");
```

That should do it?

Comment: Will only replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 10):

```
function decodeParameter(param) {
   return decodeURIComponent(param.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Comment: You need to do the plus-sign replace _before_ the unescape, not after. Otherwise, real plus signs will get converted to spaces.

Comment: Actually the characters * @ - _ + . / aren't affected by escape/unescape and this will still remove valid + signs in a url. encodeURI/decodeURI (which should actually be used for urls), has an even longer list of reserved characters ;/?:@=&# and special characters $-_.+!*'(), allowed as per RFC 1738, which will remain unchanged. By the looks of things this issue is still unresolved.

Comment: [Deprecated unescape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)

Comment: @SimoneMelloni I've updated my answer. I know `escape`/`unescape` are deprecated, but look at the original response date ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is an ambiguous thing, because you don't really know whether the `+` means a space or an actual plus sign. If you are also responsible for creating the URLs, you can solve this by using an appropriate URL encoding function which will use %20 to encode spaces. If you are just collecting them from somewhere else, well, you are left with the option of assuming that every `+` means a space :).

You can replace all `+`s using this code:

```
your_text.replace(/\+/g," ");
```